Is there any way to include query params in active class in NuxtLink?
So I made some filters using route.query params and I use NuxtLink to set/remove the filters in the url. Problem is, router-link-active and router-link-exact-active are applied to all NuxtLinks with the same base url. How can I prevent these active states on the base urls and only set them on the entire url, including the route.query?
For instance:

/blog/posts works correct
/blog/posts/[slug] (route param) works correct
/blog/posts?page=1 (route query) not working, all links with base url are marked active

I hope anyone can help me out :-)
